# get _id using groupBy with Laravel MongoDB by jenssegers

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent, aggregation-framework, jenssegers-mongodb

I am currently having trouble getting the value of _id when I use either groupBy or distinct. The values of groupBy/distinct replaces the value of _id.

how do I use the library properly to achieve this?

here is the library
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

<s>or if you can show me how to use PHP mongo's aggregate to correctly replicate the groupBy or Distinct behavior, that would be much appreciated. :)</s>

Thank you very much!

Comment: share some code, that you might've written so far, to show in which direction, and how much, you've worked so far

Comment: It's actually just a simple groupBy() that I need. Nothing complicated.

Comment: I just settled with using the library's `raw` method and doing the native MongoCollection::aggregate from the callback, as seen here http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

there is also http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.group.php which returns everything. unadvisable though.

Answer (score 0):

IDs aren't relevant in these cases, as the results do not correspond to individual rows, but aggregations thereof. If you wanted an ID to be returned, you can't use aggregate functions.

Perhaps the premise of your query is not set up correctly. What is it you are trying to achieve?